# Рендеринг ajax ответа в модальное окно bootstrap на jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, bootstrap4, render

Моя проблема в следующем: В макет циклом PHP выводится список записей к мастерам. У каждого мастера свои рабочие дни и график работы. Под каждой записью кнопка "изменить время записи". По клику на кнопку получаю id мастера и отправляю ajax запрос в хелпер, где из базы данных получаю расписание конкретного мастера и занятое время. Ajax-ответ выводит в модальное окно расписание списком без учета стилей и занятого времени. Пробую передать id мастера прямо в модальное окно, но PHP его не видит. Вопрос: можно ли каким-то образом передать в модальное окно переменную PHP и обработать её или только отрисовывать Ajax-ответ на jQuery?

```
     

<!--script.js-->
       $(document).ready(function() {
          $('.btn').click(function(e) {
            var mas_id = $(this).attr('data-master');
            $.ajax({
              url: 'helper.php',
              data: {
                'master_id': mas_id
              },
              type: 'post',
    
              success: function(data) {
                //alert("SUCCESS: " +data);
                $('.master_id').children().html("ID: " + data);
                console.log("SUCCESS: ", data);
              },
              error: function(error) {
                alert("ERROR:  " + error);
                console.log("ERROR:", error);
              }
            });
          });
    
        });
   
    
 <!-- index.php -->
         <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <?php
        require_once('helper.php');
        foreach($masters as $master){ ?>
          <div class="blog-post-title"><strong>Имя мастера: </strong>
            <?= $master['name']?>
          </div>
          <div class="blog-post"><strong>Профессия: </strong>
            <?= $master['profession']?>
          </div>
          <div class="blog-post"><strong>Услуга: </strong>
            <?= $master['service']?>
          </div>
          <div class="blog-post"><strong>Стоимость: </strong>
            <?= $master['cost']?>
          </div>
          <div class="blog-post"><strong>Рабочие дни: </strong>
            <?= $master['work']?>
          </div>
          <div class="blog-post"><strong>Время работы: </strong>
            <?= $master['hours']?>
          </div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#rpl" data-master="<?= $master['id'] ?>">Изменить время записи</button>
          <?php
        }
        ?>
          <!-- Modal -->
          <div class="modal fade" id="rpl" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Данные мастера</h5>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <div class="master_id"><strong></strong></div>
                  <div class="blog-post"><strong>Услуга: </strong>
                    <?= $master['service'] ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="blog-post"><strong>Стоимость: </strong>
                    <?= $master['cost']?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="blog-post"><strong>Рабочие дни: </strong>
                    <?= $master['work']?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="blog-post"><strong>Время работы: </strong>
                    <?= $master['hours']?>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Understood</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    
    <!-- helper.php -->
        <?php
        $masters = [
            [
             'id' => '1',
             'name' => 'Степан',
             'profession'  => 'Барбер',
             'service' => 'Бритье бороды',
             'cost' => '1500 руб.',
             'work' => 'Понедельник',
             'hours' => 'c 8:00 - 12:00'
            ],
            [
             'id' => '2',
             'name' => 'Варвара',
             'profession'  => 'Парикмахер',
             'service' => 'прически /креативные',
             'cost' => '1500 руб.',
             'work' => 'Вторник',
             'hours' => 'c 13:00 - 22:00'
            ],
            [
             'id' => '3',
             'name' => 'Алина',
             'profession'  => 'Брови, Ресницы',
             'service' => 'наращивание /4D',
             'cost' => '650 руб.',
             'work' => 'Среда',
             'hours' => 'c 8:00 - 22:00'
            ],
            [
             'id' => '4',
             'name' => 'Четверг',
             'profession'  => 'Массаж',
             'service' => 'Антистрессовый',
             'cost' => '1200 руб.',
             'work' => 'Понедельник',
             'hours' => 'c 8:00 - 16:00'
            ],
        ];
        $master = null;
        if(isset($_POST['master_id'])){
            $master_id = $_POST['master_id'];
                /*foreach($masters as $item)
                    if($item['id'] == $master_id){
                        $master = $item;
                    }*/
            echo $master_id;
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Ответ: да, можно отрисовать Ajax-ответ расписание мастера в модальном окне в виде таблицы на jQuery с сохранением всех стилей.

Comment: Могу, но не хочу.

Comment: Понял. Подскажите, как гуру программирования, а в модальное окно передать id , чтобы на php сделать выборку из базы и вывести расписание конкретного мастера, реально? То есть id  я через атрибут кнопки передаю в модалку, но PHP его не видит.

Comment: Реально. (Вы не чувствуете, что с Вашими вопросами что-то не так?)

Answer (score 0):

0. выучите основы, а потом уже пытайтесь что-то писать
1. нужно вешать обработчик не на `click`,а на событие `shown.bs.modal`
2. для доступа к data атрибутам лучше использовать `$.data()` (`$.data('master')`)
3. нужно либо все данные для модального окна передавать данные для отображения data атрибутами(в этом случае может потребоваться [обновлять высоту окна](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/modal/#handleupdate)), либо сделать для каждой записи отдельное модальное окно(т.е.генерировать их в цикле, id естественно должны отличаться)

Comment: Спасибо за Ваше внимание, пробовал подвешивать и на shown.bs.modal, и принимать в модалку ajax. Безрезультатно. Окно подгружается быстрее, чем сервер обрабатывает запрос. Пошел по пути передачи id в контролер и полученнный JSON объект $master  рендерить в модалку на jQuery,  иначе никак.

Comment: пардон, событие `show.bs.modal`

Comment: "и полученнный JSON объект $master рендерить в модалку на jQuery" проще тогда уж сразу сделать "для каждой записи отдельное модальное окно(т.е.генерировать их в цикле, id естественно должны отличаться)"